# How to configure pgsnmp on debian?

Tags: postgresql, snmpd

Can someone help me with the configuration of pgsnmp on debian? I tried it with a tutorial on official web, but it dint work 
http://pgsnmpd.projects.pgfoundry.org/.

After adding command make install, output:

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/contrib/pgsnmpd-1.0# make install
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/contrib'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.4/contrib'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pgsnmpd.conf pgsnmpd.sql '/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/contrib/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 README.pgsnmpd '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.4/contrib/'
/usr/bin/install -c  pgsnmpd '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin'
```

I don't know how to continue to configure it right. I didn't find any tutorials on this topic. Can someone help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.4/contrib/README.pgsnmpd` already?